# What is difference between using function name and nickname(made from typedef) when declare another function?

Tags: c, visual-studio, struct, scope, declaration

when I use name from typedef, there was so much errors. But after i modify name to origianl name, it works. I want to know what is different between them.

```
void SwapPoint(Point *pos1, Point *pos2);
//errors

void SwapPoint(struct point *pos1, struct point *pos2);
//it works


void SwapPoint(Point *pos1, Point *pos2);
typedef struct point
{
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
}Point;

void SwapPoint(Point *pos1, Point *pos2)
{
    Point temp;
    temp = *pos1;
    *pos1 = *pos2;
    *pos2 = temp;
}


there's no ')' in front of '*'
there's no '{' in front of '*'
there's no ';' in front of '*'
```

Comment: It is not *function names* that are typedefed in any of your examples.  It is *parameter types*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both function declarations:

```
void SwapPoint(Point *pos1, Point *pos2);
//errors

void SwapPoint(struct point *pos1, struct point *pos2);
//it works
```

even if you wrote that "it works" for the second function declaration, are invalid in C. Pay attention to that the visual-studio compiler has numerous bugs and its own language extensions that do not satisfy the C Standard.

The first declaration is invalid because the name `Point` is not yet defined.

The second function declaration is invalid because the type `struct point` is invisible outside the function declaration and does not denote the type that was defined below the function declaration. That is the parameter type is not the same as this structure declaration

```
typedef struct point
{
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
}Point;
```

From the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 4. ... If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears
>      within the list of parameter declarations in a
>      function prototype (not part of a function definition), the identifier
>      has function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the
>      function declarator.

So place the typedef before the both function declarations.

Comment: I believe that in `void SwapPoint(struct point *pos1, struct point *pos2);` the compiler now knows it will be passed pointers to a type that will at some point be declared. The type must have been declared before an actual function call is written so the compiler can check the correct types are being passed. I do not think your quote of 6.2.1 is correct here: how would that be when the type had been declared earlier?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie No, it is not C++. It does not have the notion of the elaborated type specifier. See the quote from the C Standard I provided. When the type is declared early then it was already introduced in the scope and the function type specifier denotes the same entity.

Comment: So if `struct point` had been declared earlier, _"the identifier has function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the function declarator"_ would also be the case? Then how can you say you are passing pointers to a struct?

Comment: This is very surprising to me, but I admit a strict reading of N1570 supports this conclusion.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie See my previous comment. I updated it.

Comment: So in _all_ prototypes _"the type specifier that declares the identifier appears within the list of parameter declarations in a function prototype...terminates at the end of the function declarator."_, which clearly is not the case. There must be another interpretation; otherwise all compilers are non-conformant.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie If it had been declared earlier at file scope, then 6.7.2.3/9 applies: "If a type specifier of the form _struct-or-union-identifier_ occurs other than as part of one of the above forms, and a declaration of the identifier as a tag is visible, then it specifies the same type as that other declaration..."

Comment: Checked on (old) VC2008: no problem with `void SwapPoint(struct point *pos1, struct point *pos2);`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Do not use VC. The gcc issues an error prog.c:3:16: error: ‘struct s’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration [-Werror]
 void f( struct s *p );
                ^

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I helped you to get new knowledge on C and you down-voted my answer.:) My answer is the best!:)

Comment: I accept the gcc error message and Vlad's explanation (and removed the downvote)

Comment: Vlad, I read somewhere: _"You have the capacity to learn from mistakes. You will learn a lot today."_ Guess that applies to me :-)

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of `SwapPoint` appears before the typedef for `Point`, so that name is not yet known.

Move the declaration after the typedef:

```
typedef struct point
{
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
}Point;

void SwapPoint(Point *pos1, Point *pos2);
```